# why is ngStyle not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I added the property color in my directive to the ngStyle attribute. but ngStyle is not applying any style to the element. Compiler is not showing any error at all and neither is console. I tried different syntax of ngStyle but it is still not working.

I added the app.modules code below as well. Is there any problem in loading modules.

```js
  import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
            
            // custom directive which changes background color for odd and even values of index
            @Directive({
              selector: '[appChangecolor]'
            })
            export class ChangecolorDirective implements OnInit {
              @Input() index: any;
                       color: string;
            
              constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2) { }
              // listnes to mouseenter event of the element on which custom directive is applied and calls the function
              @HostListener('mouseenter') bgColor() {
            
                if (this.index % 2 === 0) {
                  // style set through Renderer2 and not by directly accessing DOM element.
                  this.color = 'green';
                } else {
                  this.color = 'red';
                }
                  console.log(this.color);
              }
              // listens to the mouseleave event on the element on which directive is applied
              @HostListener('mouseleave') bgColorRm() {
                this.color = 'black';
                console.log(this.color);
              }
            
              ngOnInit() {
                this.index += 1;
              }
            }
```

```css
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
    import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    // custom directive imported from the respective file
    import { ChangecolorDirective } from './changecolor.directive';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ChangecolorDirective // custom directive declared as part of module
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

```html
    <!-- table displaying values from objects in users array -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Users Details</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <section class="container">
              <h2>User Details Table</h2>
              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <!-- looping thorugh array which contains keys of object and display as heading -->
                    <th *ngFor='let key of keys'>{{key}}</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <!-- looping through the users array and displaying values with the index with custom directive applied-->
                  <tr *ngFor='let user of users; index as i' appChangecolor [index]="i" [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">
                    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are keeping color property in the directive. You should emit that value to the component to update the style

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a Directive for that, try to do it in the component:

```
onMouseEnter(index) {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    this.color = 'green';
   } else {
    this.color = 'red';
   }
}

onMouseLeave() {
   this.color = 'black';
}
```

**Template**

```
<tr *ngFor='let user of users; index as i' (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter(index)" (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave()" [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">
<td>{{i+1}}</td>
<td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
<td>{{user.email}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then try with Renderer2 & ElementRef

```
this.render.setStyle(this.elementRef, 'color', this.color);
```

With ngStyle, I cant test it right now, but I think that you have to have EventEmitter. This is some simple example, just to give a directions ...

```
@Output colorChanged: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();

@HostListener('mouseenter') bgColor() {
   ....
    this.colorChanged.emit(this.color);
   ....
}

@HostListener('mouseleave') bgColor() {
   ....
    this.colorChanged.emit(this.color);
   ....
}

<tr *ngFor='let user of users; index as i' appChangecolor [index]="i" [ngStyle]="{'color': color}" (colorChanged)="this.color=$event">
```

Comment: thats the challenge it needs to be done through directive

Comment: if you use rendere2 you won't be using ngStyle then?

Comment: yes for sure, you wont need it! is that part from the challange too ;]]

Comment: but problem is that i must use ngStyle through a directive

Comment: why do you need an Eventemitter. why cant the color proerty just bind to ngstyle

Comment: as I said I cant test your code now, because im on my mobile. Those are just some solutions (ways) how you should be able to do it. This is what I can help you with, for now ;]].

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `color` property isn't correct used on `<tr>` or `<td>` elements. You should add a `<p>` tag inside each `<td>` and use the `ngStyle` on those `<p>` tags.

Something like:

```
<tr *ngFor='let user of users; index as i' appChangecolor [index]="i">
  <td><p [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">{{i+1}}</p></td>
  <td><p [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">{{user.firstName}}</p></td>
  <td><p [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">{{user.lastName}}</p></td>
  <td><p [ngStyle]="{'color': color}">{{user.email}}</p></td>
</tr>
```